# Beamer error, does not produce any output

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,charter,latexsym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{bbm}
% Setup TikZ

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]


% Author, Title, etc.

\title[xx] 
{%
  Max Weight Scheduling: Unscaled Queue Dynamics in Heavy Traffic.%
}

\author[x,y]
{
  x \and
  y
}



%\date[WABI 2006]




% The main document

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Timely Throughput Model}

\subsection{The Model}
\begin{frame}[t]{Guarantee per packet Hard Deadline Constraints}
  \begin{block}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Clients generate packets with fixed period $\tau$.  .
    \item Deadline = Period.
    \item Packets expire and are dropped if not delivered by the deadline.
    \item Hence delay of successfully delivered packet is at most $\tau$.
    \item Delivery ratio of packets that meet deadline for client $n$ should be at least $q_{n}$, i.e. 
$$\liminf\limits_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{T}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}\mathbbm{1}\{\mbox{client $i$'s packet is delivered in frame $t$}\}\geq q_{i}.$$
   \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{A Minimum Delivery-Ratio Required.}
  \begin{block}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Delivery ratio of packets that meet deadline for client $n$ should be at least $q_{n}$, i.e. 
$$\liminf\limits_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{T}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}\mathbbm{1}\{\mbox{client $i$'s packet is delivered in frame $t$}\}\geq q_{i}.$$
   \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that `\tikzstyle` is obsolete! Use `\tikzset{mystyle/.style={red}}` instead.

Answer (score 7):

I think your block environments need titles; thus

```
\begin{block}{A nice block}
```

rather than just

```
\begin{block}
```

A more minimal example that reproduces the problem is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{A nice frame}
   \begin{block}{A nice block}  %Comment out {A nice block} to crash TeX.
   \begin{itemize}
   \item abc
   \end{itemize}
   \end{block}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Finally, note that [`\[` and `\]` are preferable to `$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2417).

Comment: Or just `\begin{block}{}...\end{block}` if no title is desired for the block.